# Detect operating system version

Tags: go, operating-system

The runtime package can return the operating system. This is great because someone can just call `runtime.GOOS` which will return on of:

```
const GOOS = `windows`
const GoosAix = 0
const GoosAndroid = 0
const GoosDarwin = 0
const GoosDragonfly = 0
const GoosFreebsd = 0
const GoosHurd = 0
const GoosJs = 0
const GoosLinux = 0
const GoosNacl = 0
const GoosNetbsd = 0
const GoosOpenbsd = 0
const GoosPlan9 = 0
const GoosSolaris = 0
const GoosWindows = 1
const GoosZos = 0
```

There are some use case where this is not enough and users want to detect the specific version and just the OS family. How to detect the version of the operating system?

From the command line someone can type:

`sw_vers` on macOS

> ProductName:   Mac OS X
>
> ProductVersion:    10.14.5
>
> BuildVersion:  18F132

`lsb_release -a` on Ubuntu

> Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
>
> Description:   Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
>
> Release:   14.04
>
> Codename:  trusty

`ver` on Windows

> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.829]

I guess this can be done by using `os/exec` and parsing the output of the commands above, but is there a better way?

Comment: Not sure if there exist anything in golang, but from what I have seen in C++ some program/libraries prefer to read the information from the "source" than use the command line. Meaning that they will read and parse `/etc/lsb-release` rather than run `lsb-release -a`. On Windows you have a C function `RtlGetVersion`.

Comment: os/exec and parsing the output as u said

Comment: On contemporary Linux-based OSes the sure way to get this information is to try reading `/usr/lib/os-release`, and if that fails, try `/etc/os-release` (different distros have one of them to be a symlink to another, in various directions). The `lsb_release` binary may ligitimately not be installed on a particular system. On Windows, you may call the [`GetVersionEx` Win32 API function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-_osversioninfoexa) directly.

Comment: "The runtime package can return the operating system." Specifically, `$GOOS` is the Go compilation environment name of the target operating system.

Comment: @peterSO, I agree with you, GOOS returns the target operating system, but not the version

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53197586/13860